# Всплывание блока при попытке закрыть вкладку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно, что бы всплывал блок при попытке закрыть страницу. Попробовал много вариантов со стака, но не один не заработал
Вот примеры:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit() {
    var block = document.getElementById('leave');
    block.classList.add('open')
  }


$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    alert('hello')
  });
```

Этот заработал:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Don't leave me!";
  };
```

Но нужно как то его кастомайзить, а не просо выводить текст
Есть еще какие то варианты?

Comment: это не должно работать по определению. Представьте, что Ваша функция с чудо-диалогом глюканула. И что теперь, не закрыть вкладку? С другой стороны, пользователь может закрыть браузер или выключить комп. И этому припятствовать js'ом нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот фрагмент когда точно работает. При попытке закрыть вкладку он выдаст предупреждение, но не все браузеры разрешают его менять, и выводят свое сообщение о закрытии вкладки. Например хром говорит, `Были изменения, вы уверены что хотите закрыть окно?`

Но свое подсунуть вы не сможете, так заложено. Особенно открыть свое какие то кастомное модальное окно, не личное окно браузера.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Что-нибудь сообщить пользователю";
}
```

Раньше и хром выводил строку которую вы можете задать, но теперь и он запрещает. (По крайней мере в моем последней версии не показывает мое сообщение)

Comment: Ну, нужно засунуть целый опросник о причине отказа от услуг. Жаль, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Как вам уже ответили: нельзя изменить окно с сообщением при закрытии вкладки.
Но можно для десктопа сделать так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var block = document.getElementById('leave');
  $(block).on('click', function() {
   block.classList.remove('open');
  });
  $(document).mouseleave(function(e) {
      block.classList.add('open');
  });
});
```

```css
#leave {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: none;
}

#leave.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="leave">Уже уходите?</div>
```

Идею взял здесь: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=195